# What is the area bound by the $y$ and $x$-axis for $y=2\sin(2x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is homework. Firstly, the question that I am trying to answer is

"What is the area bound by the $y$ and $x$-axis for $y=2\sin(2x)$?"

However, I cannot seem to find the right method to solve this problem. I think I need to find the integral of $y=2\sin(2x)$ and $y=0$ for when $x \gt 0$, but I am at at loss of how to compute this.

Comment: Hint:I think you should sketch a graph and see how it goes.

Comment: The area is not very clearly defined. If there are no limitations on $x$ other than the $y$ axis, the area is infinite, whether you restrict to $x\geq 0$ or to $x\leq 0$.

Comment: I think the question is bad worded, but your idea is right. If I have understood the problem properly, I would have asked: "What is the area bound by the x-axis and the curve $y=2\sin(2x)$ for x \in [x_1,x_2]?". Without the specification of the interval on x, there's no answer.

Comment: Imho it's supposed to mean area with $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then area is equal to $2$.

Comment: @IlmārsCīrulis, I'd expect more precision in a problem posed to a student. Your guess is as good as mine (between $x = 0$ and $x = 2 \pi$, or $-infty$ and $\infty$ also are reasonable).

Comment: @vonbrand I agree that this problem is inadequately formulated. I just made, in my opinion, most believable guess about supposed meaning - like in "find area bound by $x$ and $y$ axis for $y=1-x$".
But maybe best answer is going to teacher and politely complaining.

Comment: This question must be reformulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is written, I would refer you to amWhy's answer.

On the other hand, perhaps it would be better to deal with the following similar question:

> What is the area bounded by the curve $y = 2\sin(2x)$ and the $x$ axis from $x = x_0$ to $x_1$?

In this case, the question has a definite answer, which we can do by computing the integral from $x_0$ to $x_1$. First we compute the indefinite integral:

$$\int 2 \sin (2x) \; \mathrm dx$$
$$2\int \sin (2x) \; \mathrm dx$$
(Let $u=2x$, $\mathrm d u = 2 \mathrm d x$, introduce the constant $\frac12$ outside of the integral.)
$$2 \cdot \frac12 \cdot -\cos u $$
$$-\cos 2x$$
Now evaluating the definite integral:
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} 2 \sin (2x) \; \mathrm dx = -\cos 2x_1 + \cos 2x_0 $$

Comment: Thanks I guess I didn't do a very good job trying to explain myself in the description of my question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $y = 0$ when $x = 0$ (because $y = 2\sin(2\cdot 0) = 0$). But $y = 0$ also when $x = k\cdot \pi/2$ for any integer $k$.

So you're the bounds you need to be concerned about are those x for which $x \geq 0$ and $y = 2 \sin 2x \geq 0$: $$x \in [0,\pi/2] \cup [\pi, 3\pi/2] \cup [2\pi, 5\pi/2] \cup\,\cdots \left[k\pi, \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\right],\cup\,\cdots$$

Hint: look at the following graph, and what can you conclude if $x$ has no upper bound?

[image]

Let's integrate to find the area of the curve bounded by $x = 0$ and $x = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ (see graph below):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 2 \sin (2x) \, \mathrm dx$$

Put $u=2x$, $\mathrm du = 2 \,\mathrm dx$ and we substitute appropriately. And our bounds of integration then become $u = 2x = 2\cdot 0\;$ to $\;u= 2x = 2 \cdot \pi/2 = \pi$.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} 2 \sin (2x) \, \mathrm dx\;\;=\;\;\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin u \,\mathrm du\;\; = \;\; -\cos u\Big|_0^\pi\;\;= \;\; -\cos\pi - (-\cos 0)\;\; =\;\; 2$$

[image]

Comment: I love graphs, especially those ones which oscillate. :+)